# How to schedule a job between specific time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduler, node-cron

I'm trying to schedule a job which runs for every 10 seconds between 9:00 AM to 3:30 PM from Monday to Friday using node-cron but I cannout achieve it. Here's my Node Cron code right now I can able to schedule between 9:00 AM to 4:00 PM but I want it from 9:00 AM to 3:30PM, How can I achieve this in node-cron?

```
   const job = cron.schedule('*/1 9-16 * * 1-5', () => {
      console.log(new Date());
   }, {
    timezone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [@ashish singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75057320/14569750), use two cron jobs:

```js
const cron = require('node-cron')

const job = () => {
  console.log(new Date())
}

// Each 10 seconds past every hour from 9 through 15 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday
cron.schedule('*/10 * 9-15 * * 1-5', () => job())

// Each 10 seconds from 0 through 30 past hour 15 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday
cron.schedule('*/10 0-30 15 * * 1-5', () => job())
```

CRON 1:

- `*/10`: Each 10 seconds
- `*`: Every minute
- `9-15`: From hour 9 (09:00 AM) to 15 (03:00 PM)
- `*`: Every day
- `*`: Every month
- `1-5`: From Monday to Friday

CRON 2:

- `*/10`: Each 10 seconds
- `0-30`: From minute 0 to 30
- `15`: At hour 15 (03:00 PM)
- `*`: Every day
- `*`: Every month
- `1-5`: From Monday to Friday

* Node CRON documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).

Answer (score 0):

simpler way seems to be using two scheduler

1. one for 9 to 3  `'* 9-15'`  ( this is for only min and hour )
2. one for 3 to 3.30 `'0-30 15'` ( this is only for minute and hour)